# App in iOS crashed after update to new version

Tags: ios, iphone

We have recently recieved some complains from our users that he/she cannot start the app after updating our app to the new version on Apple App Store.
The screen turns black for a second after tapping on the app's icon, and it goes back to home screen.

There is no crash log generated. Here is the only log that I can get from Xcode's Devices window.

```
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed, error -42017
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black backboardd[31] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 146: (os/kern) failure (5)
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd][146]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) Exited: Killed: 9
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) assertion failed: 11D257: launchd + 99240 [802BC42B-7AAC-33FE-8B52-C441858B62B5]: 0x16
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) assertion failed: 11D257: launchd + 99240 [802BC42B-7AAC-33FE-8B52-C441858B62B5]: 0x16
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black backboardd[31] <Warning>: Could not set priority of [146] to 1, priority: No such process
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black backboardd[31] <Warning>: Could not set priority of [146] to 0, priority: No such process
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Mar  9 13:56:54 SST-iPhone5S-Black backboardd[31] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.abc.def[0xdfdd]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

Note: please ignore the bundle identifier.

I have searched through Google and found out that it is an iOS DRM (fairplay) problem. However, most of the results I found contain the different error code in the first line of logs, and it didn't look like to be the same problem.

According to my test, I found out that this problem occurred on iOS7 only.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Or does anyone know how can I find out the meaning of the error -42017? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only your app crashing then make sure that you didn't make any changes to keychain or nsuserdefaults key in the updated version. Or make sure you handled correctly on decrypting it from storage. This might cause the app being open after a new version update.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We don't save any data to keychain, so it shouldn't be the problem, but I'm not sure about nsuserdefaults key. I will try to verify whether we made any changes to it unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

In the past `AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen()` has occurred when the app store was serving corrupt binaries to some users. Your code isn't even running, the problem is iOS trying to verify the signature on the binary and failing. iOS can tell that the app is corrupt and refuses to launch it.

The only immediate fix is for users to delete the app and reinstall it, and hope that the app store works right this time. You could also upload an update (even if nothing has really changed) so that it will show up as "new" and people with the problem will get a new copy that way. You should also contact Apple directly about this, since they're the only ones who can actually fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I believe you were talking about the problem described in this link https://marco.org/2012/07/04/app-store-corrupt-binaries.
According to the link, actually this problem caused another error code in fairplayOpen() failed which is -42110. That's why I think it is probably the different problem.

Reinstalling the app solves the problem, but I would like to avoid that option because all save data will be gone.

Uploading a new update doesn't seem to fix the problem, because some users tried updating to all updates we have released and the problem isn't resolved.

Comment: If it's a FairPlay problem, it's not your fault, and it's not something you can fix directly. It's Apple's fault and your only option is to get the broken copy replaced with a good one or else complain to Apple and hope they can do something. The different error code probably means that the exact failure reason is different, but the fact that it's FairPlay still means it's not something you can fix directly.